# Using ReactJS hooks, how should you call your api once a checkbox filter has been selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating an app where I'm calling the API using hooks (useEffect) then can filter this data using checkboxes.

But how can I only call the api once the first checkbox is selected? If the user selected a second, third, fourth etc. checkbox, I wouldn't want the api to be fetched again

Comment: It would be helpful and good practice to post some code with your question so we can see what you have done. It also gives us a starting point to work off of.

Comment: why dont you separate data fetch and filter in different places? you can fetch your data when component mount and then filter your data when click the checkbox

Comment: if you really need to fetch data and filter when clicked. maybe try `useMemo` or `useCallback`